# Read user-defined project macros programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

How can I read one of VS project environment variables oder user-defined macros such as the ${SolutionPath} from source code in C++?

I just created a new user-defined macro where I want to store the current Version of my project. I want to use this value during build as well as to show it in the GUI. Do you have any better idea to have only one place to store the current version of my product?

It seems like defining additional preprocessor flags for each project using /D might by a solution,  but I cannot get it to work to define a precompiler flag with a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional compiler option using the following format

```
/D "VariableName=\"VariableValue\""
```

This will make the macro available in the project just as if you typed:

```
\#define VariableName VariableValue
```

Comment: This is clever but what about directory names that contain backslashes?  How to get the preprocessor to interpret them literally?