# In VS, programmatically get the Linker > Additional Library Directories property, or get macro value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, macros, c-preprocessor

I need to do a runtime check on the existence of some DLLs which are located outside the working directory.  The directory in which they're stored is given in the `Linker` > `Additional Library Directories` property.  Is there any way I can get this property in C++?  The directory in question is `$(QTDIR)` and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708889/read-user-defined-project-macros-programmatically) general idea which would work great in my case, except that `$(QTDIR)` is defined with backslashes and there for the preprocessor chokes when it tries to expand it.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look at [Boost.DLL](http://apolukhin.github.io/Boost.DLL/index.html) or [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).